# "С начала" или "сначала"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

В данном случае надо писать "сначала" или "с начала"? Текст:

> В который раз начинаю главу: "Все три всадника ехали молчаливо по равнине..." Не дочитываю, книга падает. Просыпаюсь - на чем остановилась? Начинаю (с)начала: "Все три всадника..."

Answer (score 1):

В который раз начинаю  главу: **"Все три всадника ехали молчаливо по равнине..." Не дочитываю, книга падает. Просыпаюсь - на чем остановилась?**

(1) Начинаю читать **с начала (главы)**: "Все три всадника..."

(2) Начинаю читать **снова, опять, еще раз** (**о откуда? с какого места?**): "Все три всадника..."

(Из словаря: СНАЧАЛА, нареч. = Снова, опять, ещё раз).

**Вывод: Поэтому подходит первый вариант: с начала (главы).**

Comment: Спасибо! Но а разве второй вариант не подходит по смыслу? "Не дочитываю, книга падает. Просыпаюсь - на чем остановилась? Начинаю заново (=сначала): "Все три всадника..." Или нет? Мне казалось, второй вариант верен.

Comment: Здесь выбор такой: снова начинаю читать (слитно)   или  начинаю читать с начала главы (раздельно).  Мне кажется, что второй вариант более информативен.

Comment: Но вариант "сначала" не будет ошибкой в данном предложении? Дело в том, что вопрос я задавала вчера, ответ как раз  был нужен вчера вечером. И в итоге я выбрала вариант "сначала". Исправить уже нет возможности. Поэтому волнует: будет ли слитное написание ошибкой в данном случае?

Comment: Вряд ли  здесь вообще можно говорить об ошибке,  возможны оба варианта, но они имеют разные оттенки смысла (это и нужно объяснить): (1) начинаю читать снова (не указываю откуда); (2) начинаю читать с того же места.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Не хочется Вас огорчать, @Анна, но, истины ради, должен сказать. Исходя из контекста, куда логичней писать раздельно ("с начала"). Человек не помнит, на чем остановился, и поэтому начинает читать с начала главы.

Answer (score 1):

**Начинаю с начала**

Из контекста следует, что человек не помнит, на чем остановился, и поэтому начинает читать **с начала главы**.